# How to hide and show the legend in visualization - spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a multiple bar chart both of them have a legend. I have a button in text area the will trigger to show or hide those legend in visualization. Does anyone have the idea using iron python. THank you in advance.

so far i have this code in my action control that works only in one bar chart.

```
#this script hide and show the legend
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()

#Hide the legend
if myVis.Legend.Visible :
    myVis.Legend.Visible = False

else :

    myVis.Legend.Visible = True
```

Comment: "Multiple Bar Chart"..."Only works in one chart"... as in, you have more that one bar chart on the page, or you have one bar chart with multiple bars (maybe a color by or something)?

Comment: Yes. I have multiple bar chart on the page. The code that i found is working only to one bar chart. i need something to hide and show those legend found on the page using one button.

Answer (score 1):

`myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()` is only referencing one visualization on the page. Thats why only one legend is being disabled/enabled. You have two choices. One, Add another parameter like `myVis2` and duplicate your code to enable/disable for that parameter. Two, write a loop that finds all bar charts on the page and enables/disables. That would look something like this:

```
#For the active page
for vis in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    #If the viz is of type BarChart
    if vis.TypeId == VisualTypeIdentifiers.BarChart:
```

After that, apply the code to enable/disable by vis.

*I did not run that code in Spotfire yet, but it should be very close to what you need